# How to register IQ handler in Ejabberd elixir module?

Tags: erlang, elixir, ejabberd

I'm trying to register IQ handler in elixir module (using Ejabberds gen_iq_handler module), but cannot make it work. It seems that it registers the handler, but function is not called.

Registration of hooks works as expected (calling on_presence function), but handler is not picked up.

`:gen_iq_handler.add_iq_handler` returns `:ok`

I've tried passing fully qualified name (atom) for function (e.g. `:"Elixir.ModPresenceDemo.on_iq_received"`) without success and passing namespace parameter as char list also without success

Here are start and on_iq_received functions:

```
def start(host, _opts) do
  info("Starting ejabberd module Presence Demo #{host}")
  Ejabberd.Hooks.add(:set_presence_hook, host, __MODULE__, :on_presence, 50)
  result = :gen_iq_handler.add_iq_handler(:ejabberd_sm, host, "module:test", __MODULE__, :on_iq_received)
  info(host)
  info(__MODULE__)
  info(result)
  :ok
end
...
def on_iq_received(iq) do
  info('Received data for IQ handler')
  IO.inspect(iq)
  iq
end
```

upon calling handler with iq stanza:

```xml
<iq type="set" id="test" to="<user>@<host>">
  <query xmlns="module:test"/>
</iq>
```

I get IQ error stanza with error code 400:
`Unknown tag <query/> qualified by namespace 'module:test'`

Comment: Just a wild guess: try to change a binary to charlist in call to `:gen_iq_handler.add_iq_handler` since most erlang modules do expect charlists: `:gen_iq_handler.add_iq_handler(:ejabberd_sm, host, 'module:test', ...)`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin you're correct, the namespace in the call to add_iq_handler must be a binary string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild guess: add a function called `decode_iq_subel` in the handler module that returns its argument:

```
def decode_iq_subel(el) do
   el
end
```

I suspect that the error you're getting comes from [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/ebefd0d8d6bd0162f0067f85e565afde83a962ca#diff-871a58572ad146ae3f93f99560f3c811R156) - ejabberd calls the `xmpp` library to decode the subelement of the iq stanza, but since `xmpp` knows nothing of your custom namespace, it throws an `unknown_tag` error, which gets formatted into `Unknown tag ... qualified by namespace ...` [here](https://github.com/processone/xmpp/blob/d8e770495a42c22cd23536c85af5b1fd92a2139a/src/xmpp_codec.erl#L98-L101).

Comment: Good call, it calls the handler now, thx. However it seems that I get into infinite loop on server not (calling handler).  Is there some required signature for on_iq_received function (callback)? Can you point me to the documentation for ejabberd internals? i.e. I would like to figure out these types of errors on my own :)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much documentation. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41707943/113848) that does something similar to what you're doing. The callback function is supposed to return either an `iq` record (like the argument it received) or the atom `:ignore` - perhaps yours is returning something else? [This](https://elixirforum.com/t/extract-erlang-record-into-elixir/13818) might be useful to get Erlang records to work in Elixir code.

Comment: Elixir development is still quite experimental, indeed. We would love to make sure it is more usable, so thanks for the help and feedback :)

Comment: Managed to make it work with:
```
def on_iq_received(iq(type: :get, from: from, to: to) = iq_stanza) do
  info("Received data for GET IQ handler")
  iq(iq_stanza, type: :result, from: to, to: from)
end
```
and
```
defmodule Stanza do        
  require Record           
  Record.defrecord(:iq, Record.extract(:iq, from: "deps/xmpp/include/xmpp_codec.hrl"))
end
```

Comment: This is not just a quirk with Elixir development. I was struggling with this issue while writing a module in Erlang. The equivalent code in legoscia's answer in Erlang is what solved the problem.

`decode_iq_subel(El) -> El.`

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted legoscia's. To add to what a smart mind like @legoscia, its because [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/1fd75265d6c28ccae1bb3b2aa53c858984f29053/src/gen_iq_handler.erl#L128) demands a module(Your module containing the custom logic) should have decode_iq function... Look at the surrounding code, and try to understand whats its doing.

if you want to understand the flow.. start from [this](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/1fd75265d6c28ccae1bb3b2aa53c858984f29053/src/gen_iq_handler.erl#L73) function